# Wpf ScrollViewer Scroll Amount

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

Is it possible to change the amount that the WPF ScrollViewer scrolls? I am simply wondering if it's possible to change the scrollviewer so that when using the mouse wheel or the scrollviewer arrows, the amount of incremental scrolling can be changed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The short answer is: there is no way to do this without writing some custom scrolling code, but don't let that scare you it's not all that hard.

The ScrollViewer either works by scrolling using physical units (i.e. pixels) or by engaging with an IScrollInfo implementation to use logical units. This is controlled by the setting [the CanContentScroll property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll.aspx) where a value of false means "scroll the content using physical units" and a value of true means "scroll the content logically".

So how does the ScrollViewer scroll the content logically? By communicating with an IScrollInfo implementation. So that's how you could take over exactly how much the content of your panel scrolls when someone performs a logical action. [Take a look at the documentation for IScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo.aspx) to get a listing of all the logical units of measurment that can be requested to scroll, but since you mentioned the mouse wheel you'll be mostly interested in the MouseWheelUp/Down/Left/Right methods.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple, complete and working **WPF** `ScrollViewer` class that has a data-bindable `SpeedFactor` property for adjusting the mouse wheel sensitivity. Setting `SpeedFactor` to 1.0 means identical behavior to the WPF `ScrollViewer`. The default value for the dependency property is **2.5**, which allows for very speedy wheel scrolling.

Of course, you can also create additional useful features by binding to the `SpeedFactor` property itself, i.e., to easily allow the user to control the multiplier.

```
public class WheelSpeedScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SpeedFactorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SpeedFactor),
                                    typeof(Double),
                                    typeof(WheelSpeedScrollViewer),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(2.5));

    public Double SpeedFactor
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(SpeedFactorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SpeedFactorProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ScrollInfo is ScrollContentPresenter scp &&
            ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            scp.SetVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset - e.Delta * SpeedFactor);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Complete XAML demo of 'fast mouse wheel scrolling' of around 3200 data items:

<sub>*note*: 'mscorlib' reference is only for accessing the demonstration data.</sub>

```
<UserControl x:Class="RemoveDuplicateTextLines.FastScrollDemo"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <local:WheelSpeedScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Type sys:Object},Path=Assembly.DefinedTypes}" />
    </local:WheelSpeedScrollViewer>

</UserControl>
```

Fast mouse wheel:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a behavior on the scrollviewer. In my case `CanContentScroll` did not work. The solution below works for scrolling with the mouse wheel as well as draging the scrollbar.

```
public class StepSizeBehavior : Behavior<ScrollViewer>
{
    public int StepSize { get; set; }

    #region Attach & Detach
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        CheckHeightModulesStepSize();
        AssociatedObject.ScrollChanged += AssociatedObject_ScrollChanged;
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.ScrollChanged -= AssociatedObject_ScrollChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
    #endregion

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    private void CheckHeightModulesStepSize()
    {
        var height = AssociatedObject.Height;
        var remainder = height%StepSize;
        if (remainder > 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(StepSize)} should be set to a value by which the height van be divised without a remainder.");
        }
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        const double stepSize = 62;
        var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)sender;
        var steps = Math.Round(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset / stepSize, 0);
        var scrollPosition = steps * stepSize;
        if (scrollPosition >= scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
            return;
        }
        scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollPosition);
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
<ScrollViewer MaxHeight="248"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:StepSizeBehavior StepSize="62" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: I think your solution is better because of 'as well as draging the scrollbar'. I'm trying to adopt this but many red underlines are showing......Behavior<ScrollViewer>, AssociatedObject, i:Interaction.......could you please kindly share complete code? Thank you !

Comment: I have no way to look up that code right anymore. I assume the red lines come from intellisense which does not know the `<i:Interaction.Behaviors>`. You should include the namespace in the XAML document and the issue is probably resolved.With respect to the Associated object, if you google for `Behavior.AssociatedObject Property` you will find an MSDN page.

Comment: hmm...added interactivity.dll (expression blend) through nuget and everything is ok with your guide above. However, I modified value of the StepSize in xaml and in _scrollchanged event but cannot feel any better change....How can I set the value to see significant change..?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add to Drew Marsh accepted answer - while the other suggested answers solve it, in some cases you cannot override the `PreviewMouseWheel` event and handle it without causing other side effects. Namely if you have child controls that should receive priority to be scrolled **before** the parent `ScrollViewer` - like nested `ListBox` or `ComboBox` popups.

In my scenario, my parent control was a `ItemsControl` with its `ItemsPanel` being a `VirtualizingStackPanel`. I wanted its logical scrolling to be 1 unit per item instead of the default 3. Instead of fiddling with attached behaviors and intercepting/handling the mouse wheel events, I simply implemented a custom `VirtualizingStackPanel` to do this.

```csharp
    public class VirtualizingScrollSingleItemAtATimeStackPanel : VirtualizingStackPanel
    {
        public override void MouseWheelDown()
        {
            PageDown();
        }

        public override void MouseWheelUp()
        {
            PageUp();
        }

        public override void PageDown()
        {
            LineDown();
        }

        public override void PageUp()
        {
            LineUp();
        }
    }
```

then we use that panel like we normally would in our xaml markup:

```xaml
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <controls:VirtualizingScrollSingleItemAtATimeStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Obviously my scenario is contrived and the solution very simple, however this might provide a path for others to have better control over the scrolling behavior without the side effects I encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to ensure whole numbers on scrollbar1.ValueChanged:

```
scrollbar1.Value = Math.Round(scrollbar1.Value, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```