# Set line and page size for ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it possible to set the number of logical units the `ScrollViewer` should scroll when either clicking the arrows of the scrollbar (line up, line down) or inside the scrollbar (page up, page down)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ScrollBar verticalScrollBar = scrollViewer.Template.FindName("PART_VerticalScrollBar", scrollViewer) as ScrollBar;
verticalScrollBar.SmallChange = 5;
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/577fdd3a-e416-43ec-b2a0-9d36ba8be3f3/

Other than that, I can't find any out-of-the box solution without you rolling your own.

[Wpf ScrollViewer Scroll Amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639505/wpf-scrollviewer-scroll-amount)

Comment: Thanks, especially for the links. Logical scrolling as supported by `CanContentScroll` was what I wanted to implement. Because I needed it for a `WrapPanel`, I created a custom control deriving from `WrapPanel` and made it implement `IScrollInfo`. My implementation is based in [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo).

Comment: Addition: I created my own `WrapPanel`, because the default one doesn't support `CanContentScroll`.